# Cargar parte de CSS en una página

Tags: css, css3, seo

Una consulta, existe alguna forma de cargar solo una parte del CSS en una página?, por ejemplo que se tenga un CSS de 500 lineas.... y en un html no ocupo cargar todos sino solo una parte, mas que todo pensando en rendimiento

Graicas por su ayuda

Comment: Dividelo en archivos diferentes.

Comment: Si buscas una solución via html y css, lo mejor es que dividas tu css en varios archivos y llamarlos dependiendo de lo que necesitas, con js o php puedes automatizar esta importación de links. Otra opción es usar sass que  trae un sistema de importación que podría hacer lo que necesitas. ¿Has probado algo de lo anterior?

Comment: Hola @Joe, ¿por casualidad tu objetivo es no cargar estilos no utilizados?

Answer (score 1):

Sii es posible con JQuery

Puedes traer el html que quieras e insertarlo en el DOM

**JS**

```
<script>
var post=$.post('<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>',{
    funcion:'FUNCION'
},function(msg){
    $("body").append(msg);
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
if($_POST["funcion"]=="FUNCION"){
    ?>
    <style>
        /*ESTILOS*/
    </style>
    <?
    exit();
}
if($_POST["funcion"]=="FUNCION2"){
    ?>
    <style>
        /*ESTILOS 2*/
    </style>
    <?
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola @Ruben ,gracias por tu respuesta... pero por ejemplo tengo un CSS externo con 500 lineas, de la 1 a la 350 la uso para una pagina  y de la 351 a la 500 en otro pagina... como haria para no tener que cargar todo el archivo de CSS en ambas HTML ? Gracias

Comment: Tendrias que dividirlo y cargarlo por partes donde lo requieras

Comment: Cuando dices dividirlo, seria como tener varios CSS y de ahi cargar cada uno en cada página ?

Comment: Si o tenerlos todos en funciones que puedas mandar llamar tipo lo que te pongo en la respuesta

Comment: ¿Que quiere decir 500 líneas de código? En producción tendrías que tener un css minificado o sea una sola línea de código. Si 500 líneas significa 500 reglas CSS, esto quiere decir que es un css minúsculo. El css sin minificar de Css-tricks por ejemplo pasa de 8800 líneas de código, y el de Bootstrap pasa de 9000

Comment: @enxaneta puede que su interés no sea el rendimiento

Comment: @enxaneta, lo de las 500 lineas fue un ejemplo como lo puse en el primer comentario,, pero si, tienes razon, en producción deberia de ir minificado, pero lo que busco es la forma de no tener que cargar todo el CSS, de ahi la consulta.... gracias por tu respuesta...